# Part of salary from gross revenue

Tags: salary, hiring-process, negotiation, employment-agreement

I'm about to negotiate the dollars on a long-term project.

What i want is to get part of my salary as a percentage of the gross revenue. 
So, it's gross **revenue** - not gross profit or stock options of any kind.

Is this too out of the ordinary to ask? Would it be a big hassle 
for them to arrange this - would they have any concerns?
Should there be any specific terms that I should ask for in this arrangement?

I want this, because I want to be/seen on the same boat as them. 
It's an established, successful start-up and I like the team and the project.

This'll give us both the "feeling", right from the start, that I'm a heartful 
contributor and not just an employee.

**UPDATE:**

this is **not** to ask for a big chunk of their money. But merely to ask part of my salary as a fixed % of their revenue based on the last 2-3 yrs' figures. If they make more, so will I and vice versa. a company's success boils down to gross revenue. We'll be on the same side looking at how we did.

Gross profit wouldn't put us on the same boat. A company can turn thin air into money and still show no profit. It'd be like letting someone else in on managing my earnings.

Comment: Do you have a fallback position that's less open-ended? Perhaps bonuses tied to volume targets might be more palatable to the founders

Comment: @TrentBartlem what's "bonuses tied to volume targets", why would I need a fallback position? I don't know these terms - just want a percentage of what the company makes before any deductions

Comment: isn't this just asking for equity?

Comment: @bharal i don't think it is. i won't be owning any % of the company - will only be given %revenue.

Comment: @xavierz which is tons better than owning part of company.

Comment: "a company's success boils down to gross revenue."  No a company's success is due to net revenue (aka profit).  A company that only grows gross revenue, while staying continuously in the red is one that will fail as soon as it runs out of VC to fleece.

Comment: Sounds more like something you would see in MLM scams than legitimate businesses.

Comment: “If they make more” - Your using the wrong terminology if you want your salary based on what they made, just because a company brought in a million dollars in gross revenue, doesn’t mean they a single penny to pay you. A percentage of their Net revenue, after they receive pay their bills, is what your after.  Of course a percentage of net revenue is typically held for stock holders of the company.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul owning %revenue is "tons of better than owning %company"(?) - how's that? say if at most i'll ask $50K-- adding up to some tiny fraction, eg. 0.01%of the revenue.  0.01% is fixed here, not $50K. if they make half the revenue next yr, 25K instead of 50K'll go into my pocket. and i'll earn more out of that same % if the company earns more. i don't see how this compares "tons better" to owning shares. seen your comment just now

Comment: @xavierz And what do you think people with shares make when company is underperforming like that? Usually nothing. And yet you've now made 25k.

Answer (score 8):

> Is this too out of the ordinary to ask?

Yes, it is. This would put you at risk of having negotiations cut off and binned. If that isn't a problem for you then go for it.

Anything out of the normal box is risky if you don't have some sort of extraordinary leverage in terms of skill set or perhaps personal connection.

> This'll give us both the "feeling", right from the start, that i'm a heartful contributor and not just an employee.

This doesn't make sense. You may get a hearty feeling, but no one else in their right mind will.

Comment: Though if you are Hollywood A list you can get a percentage of gross :-)

Comment: love the comment on the heartiness. Straight to the point, as usual, @Kilisi

Answer (score 3):

> Is this too out of the ordinary to ask?

I worked in many startups. In my entire career I never encountered a situation where a portion of a contributor's salary was based on revenue, not achievement, not profits, or anything else.

I imagine it could make sense if for some reason the company cared solely about revenue, and not profitability, or quality, or other metrics.

That said, obviously you can ask for anything, no matter how unusual.

> Would it be a big hastle for them to arrange this - would they have
>   any concerns?

Other than setting up the accounting, it wouldn't likely be a hassle at all.

I suspect the major concern would be a startup giving away a lot of money to one individual, while losing money.

And as @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight points out, the company might decide you'd be difficult to work with and withdraw their offer.

> i want this, because i want to be/seen on the same boat as them.

Unless there are others in your company with this unusual arrangement, I can't see how this puts you "in the same boat".

Comment: The danger OTOH is that by asking for something crazy you might cause the company to decide you'd be difficult to work with and withdraw their offer.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight that's my main concern, why I brought it up here

Comment: Not to mention that by asking for part of gross revenue you are making lots of cash whether the company makes profit or not, so you do not actually care about the success. It's a prosperous ask and I would see it as a joke, and when confirmed as not, end that interview right there. Actually bonuses based on gross rev will make it more difficult for the company to turn profit, hardly what "someone in it for the long haul" wants.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is:

Even if there is no profit, and the valuation of the company goes down, I as an employee want to get a positive bonus while people who invested money into the company rack up losses.

So, no, probably not going to happen:

- Even if you invest money into a company, you don't get part of the revenue.
- Variable salary is for letting employees participate in good times of the company. What you suggest reduced the potential profit proportional to the revenue.